# Columns misaligned in email from shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sendmail

I am trying to create a script to alert me when a unix FS exceeds a certain %used.  I have successfully created the script and am able to trigger the alert to my email but I am stuck trying to format the output to be easy to read.  Below is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh
#****************************************************************************************************************************
#Check all Filesystems and see how much space is being used
#****************************************************************************************************************************
set -x

# Load the .profile for the user
. /home/user/.profile

hostname=`uname -n`
Mail_ID="mail@mail.com"

subject="Check File Systems on $hostname"
dfoutput=/tmp2/user/logs/$hostname/dfoutput.txt
dfcleanoutput=/tmp2/user/logs/$hostname/dfcleanoutput.txt
badfilesizelog=/tmp2/user/logs/$hostname/badfs.txt
limit=70

rm $badfilesizelog

df -g | awk '{if ($1 != "Filesystem") print $1, $4, $7}' > $dfoutput

sed -e 's/%//' -e '/-/d' -e '/.*ora/d' -e '/.*var/d' -e '/.*usr/d' -e '/.*monitor/d' $dfoutput > $dfcleanoutput


cat $dfcleanoutput |
while read var1 var2 var3;
do
if [ $var2 -ge $limit ]
then
printf '%-90s %-50s %50s\n' $var1 $var2 $var3>> $badfilesizelog
fi
done


[ -f $badfilesizelog ] && cat $badfilesizelog | mail -s "$subject" $Mail_ID || echo "Do Nothing"
```

This is the output that is in the email from this script:

```
/dev/fs                  70                  /apps
host:/disk_test                75               /test_software
host:/schema_backup              71               /schema_backup
```

As you can see it is not aligning everything as I would want it to like below:

```
/dev/fs                  70                  /apps
host:/disk_test          75                  /test_software
host:/schema_backup      71                  /schema_backup
```

How can I get the formatting to work correctly?  I have tried many different ways but always end up with the same alignment issues.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you need to include any code other than the `printf` line for this question? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- questions showing code are supposed to contain the **minimum** needed to reproduce an issue.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just mail client "helpfully" collapsing whitespace? Examine the message's source; it it looks like you expect, the problem is the mail client.

Comment: (On a completely different point -- why the `sed` at all? You should be able to do everything you need here with only `read`, conditional logic and parameter expansions; see also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100).

Comment: On yet another point -- there are a bunch of other issues in this code that http://shellcheck.net/ would catch; please get in the habit of running things through there before bringing them here.

Comment: Why would you source the user's profile? There is nothing in the script which uses any user variables, and it makes your script so much less robust and secure.

Comment: Using this many intermediate files is also a bit excessive. You can probably do without any without too much work.

Comment: Using temporary files and not cleaning them up when you are done isn't really good form, either. This can probably be pulled off completely without writing any files at all -- just factor more of the logic into the Awk script.

Comment: Another question: Can you build your code in such a way that anyone else can reproduce your result? http://ideone.com/OtUXH0 looks perfect.

Comment: Aside: `df` is only guaranteed to have output in a specific format when the `-P` (POSIX) argument is given and, on GNU systems, the `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` environment variable is set (enabling 512-byte block size... which is silly, but is what the standard calls for). Get used to giving that argument whenever its output is intended to be programmatically parsed; otherwise, your script won't behave identically between different operating systems.

Comment: BTW, to be clear -- using temporary files with hardcoded names, **especially** in world-writable directories such as `/tmp`, is actually a security risk; opens you up to symlink attacks, whereby an attacker with fewer privileges can overwrite/corrupt other files on your system by getting your script to do their dirty work for them.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy What's `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` ensure that not using it leaves open to output variation?

Comment: @EtanReisner, I'm not quite sure I follow the question -- but exporting `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` ensures, in this context, that `df -P` uses the POSIX-specified block size on GNU systems, which would otherwise deviate from the standard (and thus from non-GNU implementations of `df -P`) by using 1024-byte blocks.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ah. I think see what you meant now. You were talking about for conforming and comparable output and not in terms of consistent machine-readability as-such (not wrapping lines and the like)?

Comment: @EtanReisner, correct; the goal was to encourage best practices for writing scripts that read from `df` in general. (If this addressed the immediate problem, it would be an answer, not a comment).

Comment: I will try and answer everything here at once.  I included the whole script as this will eventually run in a crontab (thus sourcing the .profile of the user so I do not have to reference the location of everything needed) as well as I am not sure if it was mail creating the format issues or if I am not using printf correctly here.  The /tmp2 location is actually a secure location that is a fs mount which is secured and not world read or write.

Comment: @Charles Duffy, @EtanReisner, @tripleee I am also using sed to get rid of fs I do not care about so I am needing that line.

I have update the df command as follows but the output email remains the same with the formatting not being as expected:
`df -P | awk '{if ($1 != "Filesystem") print $1, $5, $6}' > $dfoutput`

Comment: @CamelCoder07, you need that line only if you don't replace it with something more efficient. Do the work in awk, or native bash, or... well, pretty much anything else that you're already using, and you've avoided overhead and complexity. But anyhow -- before doing anything else, figure out if it's a printf problem or a mail problem. I mean, you can just look at the contents of the `badfilesizelog` file and see if the alignment is correct there; it's silly not to have done that already.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it is silly and I don't know why I have not done that but you are correct the formatting is fine in the original file, helps to get another person to look at it I guess.

Comment: Thank you all very much for the help!

Comment: Note you can always pipe your output to `column -t` to get a proper set of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a working solution using sendmail instead of mail as mail was causing the format problem I was experiencing.  Below is what I used:

```
[ -f $badfilesizelog ] && awk ' BEGIN {
 print "From: eaimgr@'$hostname'.com"
 print "To: '$Mail_ID'"
 print "MIME-Version: 1.0"
 print "Content-Type: text/html"
 print "Subject: Check File Systems on '$hostname'"
 print "<html><body><table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=3>"
 print "<tr>"
 print "<td>Filesystem</td>";
 print "<td>%Used</td>";
 print "<td>Mounted On</td>";
 print "</tr>"
} {
 print "<tr>"
 print "<td>"$1"</td>";
 print "<td>"$2"</td>";
 print "<td>"$3"</td>";
 print "</tr>"
} END {
 print "</table></body></html>"
} ' $badfilesizelog | sendmail -t
```

Comment: It's unlikely folks having trouble with `printf` will find this answer useful, since the issue wasn't specific to `printf` at all. Perhaps you might revise the question so folks who would benefit from this answer are more likely to find it? "Columns misaligned in email from shell script" might be a place to start, if you wanted to put work into improving the question to be a useful knowledgebase addition rather than deleting it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I will make the changes.  Thank you for the suggestion.